# How can I control where my enemy spawns troops?

Tags: clash-of-clans

[image: my village layout]

Clash of clans village layout.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Your opponent cannot spawn troops within a one-block radius of any building, so if you want them to spawn further away from your core base, you need to place buildings toward the outside of your base, and spread out two squares apart to get the maximum spacing.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a Clash of Clans expert but I played it for about a year or so. And I think you can't control where your enemy spawns troops.

Comment: Oh thank you for that 

Comment: No problem at all. But I can't guarantee that it's correct, like I said I am not a Clash of Clans expert.

Answer (score 0):

You can only control where enemy can not spawn troop. Enemy can't spawn troops in the highlighted area when you select any structure.

[image: Highlighted area where enemy can't deploy troops]